# Why is getStaticProps data blank?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a next 9.3 project, when I run `npm next start` or `npm run next build`, the following Page still says map cannot be used as data is null – but data is definitely being returned, it is just not being passed the page - why is this?

```
import React from 'react';

import APIService from '../utils/APIService';


function Page({ data }) {
  console.log(data);  //is empty
  return (
    <>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <div>
          {item.name}
        </div>
      ))}
    </>    
  )
};

export default Page;

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const req = await APIService.get('/items');

  const { data } = req;

  return {
    props: {
      data, // has an array if I console.log it.
    },
  }
};
```

Comment: Everything looks ok. I double checked. Can you see the array in your code editor's terminal? `getStaticProps` is executed server side.

Comment: Seeing the same thing on my end